# I am getting run-time error '6' overflow while running the macro

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, overflow

```
Option Explicit

Sub pasting_value(rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Integer, c As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
i = 1


With rs
.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
**If Cells(i + r, c - 1).Value = DateSerial(Left(CStr(rs.Fields("date")), 4), Mid(CStr(rs.Fields("date")), 5, 2), Right(CStr(rs.Fields("date")), 2)) Then
```

Comment: Try declaring `i` as `Long`. the maximum number of rows is higher than what `Integer` can hold. (while you are at it, declare `r` and `c` as `Long` too. You generally have no reason to use `Integer` in any situation)